# python: deleting numbers in a file

Tags: python, file

I need to delete numbers from a text file on windows XP. I am new to python and just installed it for data scrubbing.

I have stored the test file in C:\folder1\test1.txt

The contexts on test1.txt is just 1 line:

> This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes 134411

I want to created a file result1.txt which contains

> This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes

Here is what I tried so far

```
import os 

fin = os.open('C:\folder1\test1.txt','r')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required.
```

I am not sure what integer it is expecting.

Can you please let me know how to go about programming to get the result I want. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it look better, but I assumed that the double quotes are not actually part of the text file. Can you confirm that that is the case?

Comment: Where did this problem come from? It seems you aren't the first one on the internet to ask about it: http://www.google.ca/search?q=%22This+must+not+b3+delet3d%2C+but+the+number+at+the+end+yes+134411%22&oq=%22This+must+not+b3+delet3d%2C+but+the+number+at+the+end+yes+134411%22

Comment: interesting find, @DavidWolever. have we all just become troll-feeders?

Comment: +1 for a newbie asking a question with sample input, expected output, what they tried, and what error they got. This Never Happens.

Comment: your second argument should be an integer (the `flag` argument)

Comment: David Z. thanks for formatting. It looks better.

Comment: David W. Yes..I was doing my homework before I decided to post this question here..

Answer (score 8):

You're using `open()` in the `os` module, which takes a numeric file mode. You want instead the builtin `open()` function. Also, backslashes in strings take on a special meaning in Python; you need to double them up if you really mean backslashes. Try:

```
fin = open('C:\\folder1\\test1.txt','r')
```

Comment: You can also use: fin = open(r'C:\folder1\test1.txt','r') http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: Or just use forward slashes ;)

Answer (score 2):

according to http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations, os.open is looking for 'flag' parameter, made of one or more of [these flags](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#open-constants) which 'r' is not.  It also seems to indicate that you probably want to look into using open() rather than os.open()

Comment: nice, but actually it expects one of these http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#open-constants (the third `mode` is optional)

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(r'C:\folder1\test1.txt','r')
```